# IO stream.flush() in C#, is not clearing the data in the stream

Tags: c#

How to clear the stream before writing(Performing IO Operation) in to the device.

```
system.IO.Stream mstream=new stream();
mstream.Flush();
```

Flush is not clearing the data in the Stream.

Comment: How do you know the data is not being cleared? And, with the code you are showing, the stream can't have any data as is a new stream...

Comment: `mstream.SetLength(0);`

Comment: Stream is a abstract class. you have to instanciate a derived class

Comment: .Flush is an abstract method of System.IO.Stream, use a derived class or implement this method.

Comment: msstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); maybe works

Comment: @Oswald In my case It's showing like mstream.seek ==  false, It works only when canseek==true.